# EMDK Motorola ES400 program GPS .NET

Tags: .net, motorola-emdk, windows-mobile-gps

I'm trying to activate and program GPS in Motorola ES400. EMDK don't have any sample to do this in .NET
Does anyone have to a working example to do this?

Regard
Jonnatan

Answer (score 2):

You can find a sample application when installing the Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Standard DTK (Developer Tool Kit) 
You can find this example in:

```
C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 6.5.3 DTK\Samples\PocketPC\CS\GPS
```

C# Program description:

Demonstrates how to use managed code to write a C# Windows Mobile Global Positioning System (GPS) application. This code sample demonstrates how to wrap the native GPS APIs in a C# class. It demonstrates how to use "Platform Invoking" (PInvoke) to make calls to unmanaged APIs (in this case, CreateProcess).

Folder : \PocketPC\CS\GPS